# Android Listview SetItemChecked by _id

Tags: android, android-listview, simplecursoradapter

I've a `ListView` populated with a `SimpleCursorAdapter` (that's populated with `_id` and `personName`). I know the `_id` which I want to select but the function `setItemChecked(pos, boolean)` uses `position` instead of `_id`.

How can I know the position in the `Cursor` within the `_id` 3 for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the `position` of the item which has the `_id` you are looking for. Then use that `position` in your call to `setItemChecked(pos, boolean)`.

Comment: The best way is to iterate the SimpleCursorAdapter compare the ids with sca.getItemId() and return the position?

Comment: That is a simple way to do it, yes.